# azure slot swapping and web.config settings

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment-slots

I have several slots in azure , one for qa, one for staging and one for 'live'.  I publish to QA and staging at the same time, once QA is approved, I then want to swap staging with live (so that staging now becomes live).

My question is, as staging is a separate web app in its own right, it has its own settings in the web.config file (db connections, client id, client secret,etc) If I swap, does the web.config swap as well ? so if the settings are different, my 'live' app  no longer has the correct settings (it takes on the staging web.config settings)

Is this correct ? how can I retain my live settings when I swap deployment slots ?
also, how does this affect webjobs ? I have several of them under the web app, with corresponding app.config settings

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you can control if the settings change or stay the same during the swap. Check out the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing. From that Article:

> **Configuration for deployment slots**
>
> When you clone configuration from another deployment slot, the cloned
>   configuration is editable. Furthermore, some configuration elements
>   will follow the content across a swap (not slot specific) while other
>   configuration elements will stay in the same slot after a swap (slot
>   specific). The following lists show the configuration that will change
>   when you swap slots.
>
> Settings that are swapped:
>
> - General settings - such as framework version, 32/64-bit, Web sockets
> - App settings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
> - Connection strings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
> - Handler mappings
> - Monitoring and diagnostic settings
> - WebJobs content
>
> Settings that are not swapped:
>
> - Publishing endpoints
> - Custom Domain Names
> - SSL certificates and bindings
> - Scale settings
> - WebJobs schedulers
>
> To configure an app setting or connection string to stick to a slot
>   (not swapped), access the Application Settings blade for a specific
>   slot, then select the Slot Setting box for the configuration elements
>   that should stick the slot. Note that marking a configuration element
>   as slot specific has the effect of establishing that element as not
>   swappable across all the deployment slots associated with the app.

Comment: how do we configure the app settings and connection strings to stick to a slot, this would seem to be exactly my requirement

Comment: It is listed how to do this in the article I linked above. Directly under the Configuration for deployment slots. I'll edit the answer above to include it, but I highly recommend reading the full article to get additional information.